Laravel 11.x ldap authentication for web and basic authentication for api
I have successfully implemented authentication using ldap in Laravel 11.x with LdapRecord. However, I am unable to use Basic Authentication for api. Before using ldap, both web and api were using Basic Authentication. Now it returns 404 for api.
As an example, when sending a post request to http://192.168.56.101/api/user in api.php:
Route::get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
})->middleware('auth.basic');

I am using Insomnia with basic authentication set:

My setup as follows:
config/auth.php
'defaults' => [
    'guard' => env('AUTH_GUARD', 'web'),
    'passwords' => env('AUTH_PASSWORD_BROKER', 'users'),
],

'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'ldap',
    ],
    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],
],

'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Models\User::class,
    ],

    'ldap' => [
        'driver' => 'ldap',
        'model' => App\Ldap\User::class,
        'rules' => [],
        'scopes' => [],
        'database' => [
            'model' => App\Models\User::class,
            'sync_passwords' => false,
            'sync_attributes' => [
                'name' => 'cn',
                'email' => 'mail',
                'user_id' => 'uid',
            ],
        ],
    ],
],

When I use the api, the following is logged:

Why does it seem to be using ldap?
Is it even possible to enable ldap for both web and basic for api?
I am keen on using Basic Authentication for API because it is simplest to use.
Worse to worse, I am also OK to use ldap for both web and api as an alternative
